# How to SUM with INDIRECT in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need PHPExcel to sum fields form G31 to field upon my total field (G-the-number-depends).
A formula

```
=SUM(G31:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

which normally works, when passed to PHPExcel changes on the output into

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())&": G31"))
```

which doesn't.
My syntax in PHPExcel is:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G32', "=SUM(G31:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))");
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Rule #1 with PHPExcel..... argument separators must be a comma (`,`), not a semi-colon (`;`) (unless you've set a locale for the calculation engine)

Comment: I tested it with the working code in my answer and at this point it makes no difference, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the cell should be in the INDIRECT statement, not in SUM and mustn't contain space. That is

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("G31:"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

on the output which is triggered by

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G32', "=SUM(INDIRECT(\"G31:\"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))");
```

in PHPExcel.
This works.